# Combining Three.js and Node.js to display .obj and .mtl file for a 3d Object in the Website

Tags: html, node.js, three.js, 3d, .obj

I want to include three.js (mainly to make a rotatable 3d Sword) into my website Project.
I looked up differnet ways and find it most convinient to use an external tool to create an sword.obj and include this through the THREE.OBJloader.

1. My first Issue i came accross was that html provided through Node.js couldnt use js. One Option was to use express and the other option( I used ) was to send the js files seperately to the html.
   This works perfectly. The main reason i wanted to include this passage, is for the reason that i used the same technique to send my .obj and .mtl file to the html / js in script tags.

My simple Test Server.js is:

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 300;

var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    console.log(request.url)
    if (request.url == '/') {
        fs.readFile(__dirname + '/Test/sword.html', function (err, html) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(500, { error: err });
            }
            response.writeHeader(200, { "Content-Type": "text/html" });
            response.write(html);
            response.end();
        });
    } else if (request.url == '/JS/three.min.js') {
        fs.readFile(__dirname + '/JS/three.min.js', function (err, jsFile) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(500, { error: err });
            }
            response.writeHeader(200, { "Content-Type": "text/javascript" });
            response.write(jsFile);
            response.end();
        });
    }
    else if (request.url == '/JS/OBJLoader.js') {
        fs.readFile(__dirname + '/JS/OBJLoader.js', function (err, jsFile) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(500, { error: err });
            }
            response.writeHeader(200, { "Content-Type": "text/javascript" });
            response.write(jsFile);
            response.end();
        });
    }
    else if (request.url == '/JS/MTLLoader.js') {
        fs.readFile(__dirname + '/JS/MTLLoader.js', function (err, jsFile) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(500, { error: err });
            }
            response.writeHeader(200, { 'Content-Length':jsFile.toString().length+'' });
            response.write(jsFile);
            response.end();
        });
    }
    else if (request.url == '/3D/tent_detailedOpen.obj') {
        fs.readFile(__dirname + '/3D/tent_detailedOpen.obj', function (err, jsFile) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(500, { error: err });
            }
            response.writeHeader(200, {  "Content-Type": "application/object",'Content-Length':jsFile.toString().length+'' });
            response.write(jsFile);
            response.end();
        });
    }
    else if (request.url == '/3D/tent_detailedOpen.mtl') {
        fs.readFile(__dirname + '/3D/tent_detailedOpen.mtl', function (err, jsFile) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(500, { error: err });
            }
            response.writeHeader(200, { /* "Content-Type": "text/plain", */'Content-Length':jsFile.toString().length+'' });
            response.write(jsFile);
            response.end();
        });
    }
});


server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
    console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

My HTML File (with JS) which shall display the 3d Object:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="Sword">

    </div>
    <script src="../JS/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../JS/OBJLoader.js"></script>
    <script src="../JS/MTLLoader.js"></script>
    <script>
        window.onload = function () {
            const scene = new THREE.Scene();
            const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

            const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xffffff );
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
            document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
            //THREE.Cache.enabled = true;



            const loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
            // load a resource
            loader.load(
                // resource URL
                '../3D/tent_detailedOpen.obj',
                // called when resource is loaded
                function (object) {
                    console.log("LOADED");
                    console.log(object)
                    scene.add(object);
                },
                // called when loading is in progresses
                function (xhr) {
                    console.log(xhr.loaded);
                    console.log(xhr.total);
                    console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + '% loaded');

                },
                // called when loading has errors
                function (error) {

                    console.log('An error happened');

                }
            );
            camera.position.set(2, 2, 2); camera.lookAt(scene.position);

            const animate = function () {
                requestAnimationFrame(animate);
                renderer.render(scene, camera);
            };
            animate();
        }

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

This only includes the .obj file which after several hours of trial and error i got to work and to display. But the big Problem is the .mtl file which style the 3d Object.
When i try to include it with following Function (instead of the only obj):

```
            var mesh = null;

            var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
            mtlLoader.load('../3D/tent_detailedOpen.mtl', function (materials) {
                materials.preload();       
                var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
                objLoader.setMaterials(materials);
                objLoader.load('../3D/tent_detailedOpen.obj', function (object) {
                    mesh = object;
                    mesh.position.y = -50;
                    console.log(mesh)
                    scene.add(mesh);

                });

            });
```

But still there is no 3d, i copied beneath the mesh that is created, but i cant finde the mistake with it. Normally in my understanding it should be displayed.

```
animations: []
castShadow: false
children: [Gn]
frustumCulled: true
layers: ve {mask: 1}
materialLibraries: ["tent_detailedOpen.mtl"]
matrix: ae {elements: Array(16)}
matrixAutoUpdate: true
matrixWorld: ae {elements: Array(16)}
matrixWorldNeedsUpdate: false
name: ""
parent: Ts {uuid: "2D813A87-9F8A-430B-B66F-FE57C67ED03F", name: "", type: "Scene", parent: null, children: Array(1), …}
position: Rt {x: 0, y: -50, z: 0}
quaternion: Lt {_x: 0, _y: 0, _z: 0, _w: 1, _onChangeCallback: ƒ}
receiveShadow: false
renderOrder: 0
rotation: ge {_x: 0, _y: 0, _z: 0, _order: "XYZ", _onChangeCallback: ƒ}
scale: Rt {x: 1, y: 1, z: 1}
type: "Group"
up: Rt {x: 0, y: 1, z: 0}
userData: {}
uuid: "44EB2251-B7A3-4432-BCB4-A01D6D26F119"
visible: true
eulerOrder: (...)
id: 11
modelViewMatrix: ae {elements: Array(16)}
normalMatrix: yt {elements: Array(9)}
useQuaternion: (...)
__proto__: Pe
```

Does anyone have an Idea why it wont show? I already switched camera position to exclude the posibilty of just the camera not showing it.
Also examples of how to fully implement a 3d object through node.js are a rarity and i couldnt find one.

I would highly appreciate any help and maybe a completly other option how i can create a simple 3d Object(sword) and implement it into my node.js website.

Best Regards
Julian

Comment: `objLoader.load('../3D/tent_detailedOpen.mtl', function (object) {` You're trying to open an MTL file with `OBJLoader`. Switch the file path to point to your OBJ (`../3D/tent_detailedOpen.obj`) and it should work.

Comment: Thanks man, simple mistake. I corrected it above. This gets rid of the errors in the console but still leaves me with no 3d